# Determine the set of points $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ for which the equation for $x$ can be solved in terms of $y$ in a neighborhood of $(a,b)$

Tags: calculus

Could anyone help me with this problem, related to the implicit function theorem?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a function such that 
$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy + 2x + 2y$. Determine the set of points 
$(a, b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ for which we can solve the equation $f (x, y) = 0$ for $x$ in terms of $y$ in a neighborhood of $(a,b)$.

Comment: What "equation for $x$"? Are you talking about a level set of $f$?

Comment: @Jason I think you misread that sentence. $f(x,y)=0$ is an equation, and under certain limitations it can be solved for $x$ in terms of $y$. The problem is to find those limitations.

Comment: @Arthur I am aware of this but the OP should be clear about what they are asking. The question has since been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)=(x+y)^2+2(x+y)=(x+y)(x+y+2)$

So $f(x,y)=0\iff x=-y\quad$ or $\quad x=-2-y$

These two lines are parallel so there is no conflict of neighborhood for solving.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Take a look at the Implicit Function Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$ on [these notes](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/217.1.13f/217-20131009.pdf). Note the 3 requirements for $x$ to be implicitly defined by $y$ in a neighbourhood of $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and you should be able to find the answer.